# listview onClick return wrong result

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, search

I have custom listview with data from SQLite database. I can add and edit items. Also I have SearchVIew in toolbar to serch items by name.

The problem is that when I want to edit item, and use SearchView to find it, onClick method returns wrong id (item of the first in the list). 
If I do not use the search, then everything is fine. For example:[image: no search]

[image: search]

My class code:

```
public class ProductCategoryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ListView myProductsList;
private DataBaseHelper dataBaseHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase db;
private Cursor productCursor;
private ArrayList<Product> productList;
private int tableId;
private String dbName;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_products);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    Intent idOfGroup = new Intent(getIntent());
    tableId = idOfGroup.getIntExtra("table_id", 0);

    myProductsList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvMyProducts);

    switch (tableId) {
        case 1:
            dbName = DataBaseHelper.TABLE_MY_PRODUCTS;
            break;
    }

    //allow adding and editing products if tableId == 1
    if (tableId == 1) {
        myProductsList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                //get id by click on list view item
                String sql = "SELECT " + DataBaseHelper.COLUMN_ID + "  FROM " + dbName;
                productCursor = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
                ArrayList<Long> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
                if (productCursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        arrayList.add(Long.parseLong(productCursor.getString(0)));
                    } while (productCursor.moveToNext());
                } else {
                    throw new NullPointerException();
                }
                //sending id to another activity
                Intent intent = new Intent(ProductCategoryActivity.this, ProductAddEditActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("id", arrayList.get(position));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
    dataBaseHelper = new DataBaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
    //creating db
    dataBaseHelper.create_db();

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.newProduct:
            Intent intent = new Intent(ProductCategoryActivity.this, ProductAddEditActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    productList = new ArrayList<>();
    productList.clear();
    db = dataBaseHelper.open();
    //get data from db
    productCursor = db.rawQuery("select * from " + dbName, null);
    setProduct();
}


//product search by name
public Cursor getProductListByKeyword(String search) {
    productList = new ArrayList<>();
    productList.clear();
    db = dataBaseHelper.open();
    //get data from db by word
    productCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + dbName + " WHERE "
            + DataBaseHelper.COLUMN_NAME + "  LIKE  '%" + search + "%' ", null);
    setProduct();
    return productCursor;
}

private void setProduct() {
    //select  required columns
    if (productCursor != null && productCursor.getCount() != 0) {
        if (productCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Product product = new Product();
                product.setProductName(productCursor.getString(productCursor.getColumnIndex(DataBaseHelper.COLUMN_NAME)));

                productList.add(product);
            } while (productCursor.moveToNext());
        }
    }
    productCursor.close();
    ProductListAdapter productListAdapter = new ProductListAdapter(this, productList);
    myProductsList.setAdapter(productListAdapter);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    //the add button is hidden if tableId != 1
    if (tableId != 1) {
        MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.newProduct);
        menuItem.setVisible(false);
    }
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.searchForSee).getActionView();
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
            productCursor = getProductListByKeyword(s);
            Toast.makeText(ProductCategoryActivity.this, productCursor.getCount() + " " +
                            getString(R.string.txt_products_found),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
            return false;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
            productCursor = getProductListByKeyword(s);
            return false;
        }
    });
    return true;

}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    db.close();
    productCursor.close();
}
```

Comment: I do not understand you (long id???)

Comment: how can this help me?

Comment: @pskink but long id returns listview item id, but I need id of SQLite row, 
they are not the same id

Comment: but I use custom Adapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem in onClick method:

```
 myProductsList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                //get id by click on list view item
                long productId;
                if (productCursor.moveToPosition(position)) {
                    productId = Long.parseLong(productCursor.getString(0));
                } else {
                    throw new NullPointerException();
                }
                //sending id to another activity
                Intent intent = new Intent(ProductCategoryActivity.this, ProductAddEditActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("id", productId);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is how you are getting that id. You first get all column IDs from the table, then create an array of IDs and then choose an entry from there based on position.

Irrespective of your search results, your arrayList variable will always contain all IDs from the table. So when you access arrayList.get(position), it will return the object on that position in the table, not in the list.

You should either use `long id` or change your SQL query such that you only get entries such that your search test is honored in the SQL results.

Somethign like this perhaps

```
String sql = "SELECT " + DataBaseHelper.COLUMN_ID + "  FROM " + dbName + " WHERE " + DataBaseHelper.COLUMN_NAME + "=" + searchText;
```

Change the vars accordingly.

Even easier than that, You can simply use the `long id` passed in params.

Comment: even easier than `getItemId`: the `long id` is passed as the last parameter to `onItemClick` method

Comment: Yes. Thats right. But i am not sure if OP has correctly implemented the `getItemId` function. @Andrii, If you have correctly implemented this function in your list adapter, you can simply use `long id` passed in params.

Comment: `SimpleCursorAdapter` (or `CursorAdapter` in general) already implements all that stuff - no need to reinvent the wheel

Comment: I see. Did not know that. :P

Comment: ` Intent intent = new Intent(ProductCategoryActivity.this, ProductAddEditActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("id", id);
                startActivity(intent);`
not works, because in another activity I get data like this : Cursor productCursor = db.rawQuery("select * from " + DataBaseHelper.TABLE_MY_PRODUCTS + " where "
                    + DataBaseHelper.COLUMN_ID + " = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(extras.getLong("id"))});

Comment: Are you getting the correct ID in `onItemClick()` function now ? If so, please close this question and ask a new one since your new issue might be different.

Comment: However, if your issue is that the `long id` and the id you need are different since you are using BaseAdapter for your list, then simply implement the `public long getItemId(int position)` override of yout list adapter such that it returns the correct ID for the object which is at this position. Once you do this, your `long id` param will have the id that you return from `getItemId()`

Comment: I get correct ID if I don't use search functionality. 
That was the reason for my question, because when I search in list and after that click on searched item returns wrong id

Comment: As i said, you need to correctly implement the `getItemId` function and use `long id` in your code.

Comment: @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
this is my method from adapter

Comment: This is incorrect. Do somethign like this `return productList.get(position).id; `. Here I am assuming you have a list of Product Objects in your adapter called productList. And each Product contains a long field called id.